# How to deal with Volley Request NoTimeout

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

Hello this may not be the appropriate title for this but its the best i could come up with at the time.

I'm making a Volley Post String request to my server with no retries, to avoid duplicates from being sent. I have my retry policies set and all is dandy.

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            -1,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT ) );
```

The thing however is that if the data( could be anything, base64string etc) i am sending is small, it most definitely gets executed before the timeout and i get a response from the server.

However, when it becomes a little bulky, all the data is still sent( i see them in the db(text), and the images are uploaded to folder) , might just take a while but i never get a response back. my log shows

```
D/Volley: [15210] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[X] http://example.com/api/report 0x82d7b19 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=74996], [size=121], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
```

but onresponse or error listeners show/say nothing and this way i can't alert the user to anything or even hide the progress dialog.

Has anyone experienced this and what would you recommend. Here are other settings i've tried amongst others

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * 2,
        0,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT ) );

stringRequest.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        30000,
        0,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT ) );
```

As mentioned about,i get the sense that if the data i'm transmitting is executed before the timeout, i get a response but any thing more than that, i got no response but the information is still process. I also tried to log the volley errors just in case but none, so i need you help figuring this out.